# Possible to export layout of applications on the home screens and import it into another phone?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, import

I would like to know whether it is possible to export layout of applications on the home screens and import it into another phone.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the launcher you are using, some support this, other don't. Best way to do is to just copy the data to export to the phone to import (both need to be rooted, though)

Comment: If both phones are running the same launcher app, then you can backup the launcher on one device, and restore it on another.